# CMake Error on Compiling weechat from sources

Tags: centos6.5

I was trying to compile weechat from sources on my CentOS 6.6 machine. I installed all the below dependencies as per the README file.

- cmake
- ncurses-devel
- gcrypt-devel
- zlib-devel
- libcurl-devel

Now when I do `cmake .. -DPREFIX=/usr/local/bin` I get the following error:

`-- checking for one of the modules 'ruby-2.1;ruby-2.0;ruby-1.9;ruby-1.8'
-- checking for one of the modules 'lua5.2;lua52;lua5.1;lua51;lua5.0;lua50;lua'
-- checking for one of the modules 'guile-2.0'
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
NCURSES_INCLUDE_PATH (ADVANCED)`

Comment: triple-check ncurses-devel installed properly?